# Typescript dynamic import() of file only works with hardcoded strings

Tags: node.js, typescript, dynamic, import

I am trying to dynamically load a file in typescript using `import()`. I have managed to get it working if I hardcode the path to the file, as this:

```
import("./file").then(module => doStuff(module)); // Success
```

But as soon as I store the path in a variable, it will not find the file.
This will succeed to compile but will at runtime complain: `Cannot find module "./file"`.

```
path = "./file";
import(path).then(module => doStuff(module)); // Cannot find module "./file".
```

Is there any way to fix this, or any way to work around for the issue?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "esnext",
  "strict": true,
  "allowJs": true,
  "lib": [
    "esnext"
  ],
  "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is an interesting one lol

prefix your import with '../../' or similar (play around with it)

e.g. import(`../../${m}.ts`)

Only way to do it as the issue is with the import itself and not typescript or others.

Comment: eh, I had "back ticks" which got stripped out... fyi